# NativeScript Bundle Snapshot - ReferenceError: com is not defined

Tags: android, webpack, nativescript, snapshot

I'm trying to bundle a NativeScript App with the snapshot flag like this:

```
tns build android --bundle --env.snapshot
```

The following error appears:

```
ERROR in NativeScriptSnapshot. Snapshot generation failed!
Target architecture: x86
# Script run failed in <embedded>@736:2461
ReferenceError: com is not defined


#
# Fatal error in ../src/snapshot/mksnapshot.cc, line 175
# Check failed: blob.data.
#
```

Anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `app.scss` in the root folder had been renamed to something else. Make sure it it will pass the regex ( default: `/^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$/` ) in the `vendor.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

See [How it works](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/improving-app-startup-time-on-android-with-webpack-v8-heap-snapshot) part

> Modules included in the snapshotted bundle can still contain native
>   API calls given that **they are not evaluated immediately** upon module
>   loading. For example, the following module:
>
> require("application");
>
> var time = new android.text.format.Time(); can’t be snapshotted
>   because it touches android.text.format.**Time API which is not
>   available**. However, in this one:
>
> require("application");
>
> function getTime() {
>       return new android.text.format.Time(); } the native API access is not evaluated on module execution. Given that getTime() is called
>   later in the fully featured V8 context provided by the Android
>   runtime, we are safe to include the module in the snapshotted bundle.
>
> If the snapshotting step fails because of a reference to an undefined
>   API, try some of the following solutions:
>
> If you can change the module containing the forbidden API call, wrap
>   the guilty code in a function that is called once the app is running
>   on device Keep the module in the bundle but make sure all require
>   calls of the non-snapshotable module are executed once the app is
>   running on device: require("application"); var m =
>   require("non-snapshotable-module");
>
> function doSomething() {
>       return m.someMethod(); } The code above has a higher chance to be successfully snapshotted if it loads the non-snapshotable module when
>   it actually needs it:
>
> require("application");
>
> function doSomething() {
>       return require("non-snapshotable-module").someMethod(); } If doSomething() function is never called in snapshot context, the
>   non-snapshotable module will not be evaluated and blob generation will
>   succeed.
>
> Exclude the module containing the forbidden API call from the
>   snapshotted bundle.

So make sure you are not referencing `com` in snapshot time.